# Change BG-Image after x seconds

Tags: jquery, loops

I would like to change between two different background-images after eg. 2 seconds.
So: first bg-image_01 for 2 sec, then bg-image_02 for 2 seconds, bg-image_01 for two seconds..

How can I do that with jQuery? I know how to change the BG-image, but I have problems with looping it endlessly.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Use https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var bgchanger = setInterval(changebg,2000);
function changebg() {
   // Your BG changing code here
};
```

That'll do it.

Comment: I like how our answers are exactly the same but this is +1 and mine is -1. Some people are stupid...

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work for me; what's wrong with my script? Thx in advance. http://pastebin.com/EH5CZtDc

Comment: To update the background image use $('#target').css('background-image','url(relative_image_path)');